# How to allow users to list authorized buckets in GCP Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp

I created a storage bucket B and I granted a user as "Storage Object Viewer" on it.
The user can view bucket content with a direct link (e.g. https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/B/?project=azerty).

Is it possible to allow a user to list all buckets that he is allowed to read? It would be more user friendly to see them in Storage Browser Web console i.e. https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to list all the accessible buckets **across all cloud projects**, neither in the developer console browser nor via the `gsutil` command. Both of them only display buckets for one project at a time.

But if you specify a particular project (or stick with the one selected by default) you can list the accessible buckets inside that project in both `gsutil` (as shown in @chupasaurus's answer) and in the developer console browser. In the browser you get to the project selection popup by clicking on the project's dropdown menu in the top navigation bar.

You could try to file a feature request for it at https://issuetracker.google.com/components/187243/manage#basic, it *might* get accepted if it shows enough interest.

Answer (score 0):

From AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListAllMyBuckets.html): "The `ListAllMyBuckets` operation returns a list of all buckets **owned** by the sender of the request.". Owned, not having some access to it, and IIRC you can't see all the buckets you have read access in AWS Console either.

`gsutil -p azerty ls gs://` would show all buckets which user have List access to.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. I will rephrase my question and remove S3 references. Regarding gsutil, users would like to see buckets through GCP Web console.